# removing background 'noise' from signal images (RGB)

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, opencv

I have some signal images:
[image]

As you can inspect, some of them contain color signals and some are just gray/black color signals.
My task is to extract **pure signal with white background** only. That means I need to remove all but signal in the image.

I checked that dash lines, dotted lines, solid lines (top and bottom) have the same RGB value that are close to 0;0;0 (ex: 0;0;0, 2;2;2; or 8;8;8) in terms of RGB.

Therefore, first thing that came to my mind was to access RGB values of each pixel and assign white color if all RGB values are the same. Using this heavy computation I can extract all color signals, because RGB values are never same for colors like red, blue, green (or their shades to some extent).

However, that process would remove signals where signal's pixel values are the same. That happens with mostly black color signals (the first two samples for example).

I also thought of extracting the signal if it keeps its horizontal and some vertical continuity, but to be honest I don't know how to write the code for it.

I am not asking any code solution to this challenge. 
I would like to have different opinions on how I can successfully extract the original signal.

I am looking forward to having your ideas, insights and sources. Thanks

*Note: All of my images (about 3k) are in one folder and I am going to apply one universal algorithm to accomplish the task.*

Comment: Replacing pixels close to black with white is not "heavy computation". It's one of the simplest, cheapest things you can do in image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the horizontal and vertical lines using [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).
After finding the lines, it's simple to erase them.

Removing the lines is only the first stage, but it looks like a good starting point...
Keeping the colored pixels (as you suggested) is also simple task.

You have mentioned you are not asking any code solution, but I decided to demonstrate my suggestion using MATLAB code:

```matlab
close all
clear

origI = imread('I.png'); %Read image
I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(origI)); %Convert to binary
I = ~I; %Invert - the line color should be white.

%Apply hough transform: Find lines with angles very close to 0 degrees and with angles close to 90 degrees.
[H,theta,rho] = hough(I, 'RhoResolution', 1, 'Theta', [-0.3:0.02:0.3, -90:0.02:-89.7, 89.7:0.02:89.98]);
P = houghpeaks(H, numel(H), 'Threshold', 0.1, 'NHoodSize', [11, 1]); %Use low thresholds
lines = houghlines(I,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',25,'MinLength',200); %Fill large gaps and keep only the long lines.

%Plot the lines for debugging, and erase them by drawing black lines over them
J = im2uint8(I);
figure, imshow(I), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Draw black line over each line.
   J = insertShape(J, 'Line', [xy(1,1), xy(1,2), xy(2,1), xy(2,2)], 'Color', 'Black');
end

%Covert J image to binary (because MATLAB function insertShape returns RGB output).
J = imbinarize(rgb2gray(J));
figure, imshow(J)

%Color mask: 1 where color is not black or white.
I = double(origI);
C = (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,2)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,3)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,2) - I(:,:,3)) > 20);

figure, imshow(C)

%Build a mask that combines "lines" mask and "color" mask.
Mask = J | C;
Mask = cat(3, Mask, Mask, Mask);

%Put white color where mask value is 0.
K = origI;
K(~Mask) = 255;

figure, imshow(K)
```

Detected lines:
[image: Detected lines]

Result after deleting lines:
[image: Result after deleting lines]

Final result:
[image]

As you can see there are still leftovers.
I Applied a second iteration (same code) over the above result.

Result was improved:
[image]

You may try removing the leftovers using morphological operations.
It's going to be difficult without erasing the dashed graph.

---

### Iterating all the PNG image files:

- Place the code in an `m` file (MATLAB script file).
- Place the `m` file in the same folder of the PNG image files.

Here is the code:

```matlab
%ExtractSignals.m

close all
clear

%List all PNG files in the working directory (where ExtractSignals.m is placed).
imagefiles = dir('*.png');
nfiles = length(imagefiles);

result_images = cell(1, nfiles); %Allocate cell array for storing output images

for ii = 1:nfiles
    currentfilename = imagefiles(ii).name; %PNG file name

    origI = imread(currentfilename); %Read image

    %Verify origI is in RGB format (just in case...)
    if (size(origI, 3) ~= 3)
        error([currentfilename, ' is not RGB image format!']);
    end

    I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(origI)); %Convert to binary
    I = ~I; %Invert - the line color should be white.

    %Apply hough transform: Find lines with angles very close to 0 degrees and with angles close to 90 degrees.
    [H,theta,rho] = hough(I, 'RhoResolution', 1, 'Theta', [-0.3:0.02:0.3, -90:0.02:-89.7, 89.7:0.02:89.98]);
    P = houghpeaks(H, numel(H), 'Threshold', 0.1, 'NHoodSize', [11, 1]); %Use low thresholds
    lines = houghlines(I,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',25,'MinLength',200); %Fill large gaps and keep only the long lines.

    %Plot the lines for debugging, and erase them by drawing black lines over them
    J = im2uint8(I);
    %figure, imshow(I), hold on
    for k = 1:length(lines)
        xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
        %plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

        % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
        %plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
        %plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

        % Draw black line over each line.
        J = insertShape(J, 'Line', [xy(1,1), xy(1,2), xy(2,1), xy(2,2)], 'Color', 'Black');
    end

    %Covert J image to binary (because MATLAB function insertShape returns RGB output).
    J = imbinarize(rgb2gray(J));
    %figure, imshow(J)

    %Color mask: 1 where color is not black or white.
    I = double(origI);
    C = (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,2)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,3)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,2) - I(:,:,3)) > 20);

    %figure, imshow(C)

    %Build a mask that combines "lines" mask and "color" mask.
    Mask = J | C;
    Mask = cat(3, Mask, Mask, Mask);

    %Put white color where mask value is 0.
    K = origI;
    K(~Mask) = 255;

    %figure, imshow(K)

    %Second iteration - applied by "copy and paste" of the above code (it is recommended to use a function instead).
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    origI = K; %Set origI to the result of the first iteration

    I = imbinarize(rgb2gray(origI)); %Convert to binary
    I = ~I; %Invert - the line color should be white.

    %Apply hough transform: Find lines with angles very close to 0 degrees and with angles close to 90 degrees.
    [H,theta,rho] = hough(I, 'RhoResolution', 1, 'Theta', [-0.3:0.02:0.3, -90:0.02:-89.7, 89.7:0.02:89.98]);
    P = houghpeaks(H, numel(H), 'Threshold', 0.1, 'NHoodSize', [11, 1]); %Use low thresholds
    lines = houghlines(I,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',25,'MinLength',200); %Fill large gaps and keep only the long lines.

    %Plot the lines for debugging, and erase them by drawing black lines over them
    J = im2uint8(I);
    %figure, imshow(I), hold on
    for k = 1:length(lines)
        xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
        % Draw black line over each line.
        J = insertShape(J, 'Line', [xy(1,1), xy(1,2), xy(2,1), xy(2,2)], 'Color', 'Black');
    end

    %Covert J image to binary (because MATLAB function insertShape returns RGB output).
    J = imbinarize(rgb2gray(J));
    %figure, imshow(J)

    %Color mask: 1 where color is not black or white.
    I = double(origI);
    C = (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,2)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,1) - I(:,:,3)) > 20) | (abs(I(:,:,2) - I(:,:,3)) > 20);

    %figure, imshow(C)

    %Build a mask that combines "lines" mask and "color" mask.
    Mask = J | C;
    Mask = cat(3, Mask, Mask, Mask);

    %Put white color where mask value is 0.
    K = origI;
    K(~Mask) = 255;
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %Store result image in a cell array
    result_images{ii} = K;
end

%Display all result images
for ii = 1:nfiles
    figure;
    imshow(result_images{ii});
    title(['Processed ', imagefiles(ii).name]);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contribution, let me try to convert the code to python and apply to my images. Then I'll see how that performs. Still open for more ideas though.

Comment: I decided to use Matlab and freshly installed it on my PC. And somehow tried your code ti implement in images in a folder.
Have a look at [this](https://imgur.com/cYZabOv) and have your say please. Although the image has RGB values, why is it throwing an error?

Comment: I can't say... try to rename the relevant image to `I.png`, and execute my code as is.

Comment: It worked when I tried a single image even w/o renaming, maybe I have wrongly constructed the loop part? could you write a single code to read images in a folder using Matlab, it's almost first time for me to do that. Then I would readily accept your answer as it would solve the particular issue I am having. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check the color format of your `png` images? The common formats are RGB (bit depth 24) and Grayscale (bit depth 8). Format can also be RGBA (bit depth 32). Indexed color is also possible (bit depth 8, but viewed as colored). Each format requires different conversion steps (after `imread`).

Comment: if you saw the image I gave a link to in my  first comment, in the right side, there is `origI` variable with a value of `210x889x3 uint8`.  Isn't it enough for me to assume that the image is in RGB format? And I saw the details of an image, its bit depth is 24

Comment: Sure, but it's not assuring that all your PNG images in your folder are in RGB format.

Comment: I did check over 10 images in my folder, they are 24 bit depth, and the image that is read first `1001_8_Rel_A_05.png` is indeed 24 bit depth

Comment: The loop you have posted supposed to work. I will check it up later.

Comment: I added a code that iterates all the PNG files in the folder. Please note: The algorithm is "over-fitted" to the image you posted. There are many cases where it's going to fail extracting the signal.

Comment: Using the Hough transform to find horizontal and vertical lines is overkill. And limiting the algorithm to strictly horizontal or vertical lines might improve the results too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I know it's an overkill, and using `insertShape` for removing the lines is even more "overkill". I looked for something that is simple to implement, and not for an efficient solution. For some reason limiting the lines to strictly horizontal or vertical lines failed to work.