# How to detect a curve in a B&W image with a background grid?

Tags: javascript, image, charts, detection, curve

I am struggling to extract the curve from this image:

[image: curve]

It represents scientific data which I don't want to touch, to avoid introducing errors, so I cannot just manually redraw the line in a plot digitizer: I want to automatically extract the curve, which then I will feed into a plot digitizer.

I tried programmatically drawing a white grid over the image, trying to exactly overlap the grid and delete it; but unfortunately this is the scanning of a paper sheet, so the grid is not perfect, hence spacing between lines is not always the same.

[image: test1]

[image: test2]

Code used for grid:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  <script>
        sourcename = "converted";
        originalHeight = 0;
        originalWidth = 0;


function renderImage()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("grid");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        selectedimage = image;
        originalHeight = image.height;
        originalWidth = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.width = image.width;
        context.drawImage(image,  0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        xstep = document.getElementById("rngXstep").value*1;
        ystep = document.getElementById("rngYstep").value*1;
        xoffset = document.getElementById("rngxoffset").value*1;
        yoffset = document.getElementById("rngyoffset").value*1;
        strokewidth = document.getElementById("rngstrokewidth").value*1;
        color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        document.getElementById("xstep").value = document.getElementById("rngXstep").value*1
        document.getElementById("ystep").value = document.getElementById("rngYstep").value*1
        document.getElementById("xoffset").value = document.getElementById("rngxoffset").value*1
        document.getElementById("yoffset").value = document.getElementById("rngyoffset").value*1
        document.getElementById("strokewidth").value = document.getElementById("rngstrokewidth").value*1
        drawGrid(context,0,0,0,xoffset,yoffset,xstep,ystep,0,0,color,strokewidth);
    };
    image.src = "chart-test-2.png";
}

var drawGrid = function(context, w, h, id, xoff, yoff, xstep, ystep, xmax, ymax, color,width) {
            for (var x = 0; x <= originalWidth; x += xstep) {
                context.moveTo(1 + x + xoff, 0 + yoff);
                context.lineTo(1 + x + xoff, originalHeight + yoff);
            }


            for (var x = 0; x <= originalHeight; x += ystep) {
                context.moveTo(0, 1 + x + yoff);
                context.lineTo(originalWidth, 1 + x + yoff);
            }

            context.strokeStyle = color;
            context.lineWidth = width;
            context.stroke();
}


</script>
  </head>
  <body>
x step: <input type="text" id="xstep" name="xstep" value=4.1>
<input type="range" id="rngXstep" name = "rngXstep" value="4.1" onchange="renderImage()" step=.1><br>

y step:<input type="text" id="ystep" name="ystep" value=4.1>
<input type="range" id="rngYstep" name = "rngYstep" value="4.1" onchange="renderImage()" step=.1><br>

x offset: <input type="text" id="xoffset" name="xoffset" value=0>
<input type="range" id="rngxoffset" name = "rngxoffset" value="0" onchange="renderImage()" step=.1><br>

y offset:<input type="text" id="yoffset" name="yoffset" value=0>
<input type="range" id="rngyoffset" name = "rngyoffset" value="0" onchange="renderImage()" step=.1><br>

width: <input type="text" id="strokewidth" name="strokewidth" value=2>
<input type="range" id="rngstrokewidth" name = "rngstrokewidth" value="2" onchange="renderImage()" step=.1><br>

color: <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="white"> (red, white, blue,...)<br>

<canvas id="grid"></canvas><br>
    <img id="chart" name="chart" src="chart-test-2.png"  ><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Putting directly the image into a plot digitizer does not work, as the curve has same color of grid, and plot digitizers use color to automatically detect curves.

Then I decided to try a different approach: looking for the thickest line in the image; I coould try writing my own algorithm, scanning each single pixel and determining which one has more black neighbours ... but probably I would reinvent the wheel; I asked to ImageMagick author if his program is able to do such thing, but he said it does not.

Then I found that OpenCV implements some algorithms such as Hough Transform, Contour detector, and probably many others; but I am completely new to OpenCV, so I would need some hints about which functions best fits my need.

Can [Hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) detect also curved lines, or only segments? Can [contour detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) also detect open curves or just closed lines? Or should I use [canny edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)?

But another problem is that I need javascript examples, not C++ or Python.

But I am open to any javascript solution, OpenCV is not the only option.

Comment: I think openCV is good choice and there is an example finding curved lines. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html

Comment: Try blurring instead. I also upped the contrast and got this: https://i.imgur.com/ILHQk1v.png

Comment: Maybe I found a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476427/removing-background-noise-from-signal-images-rgb  But it's python, I need javascript :-(

Comment: Or maybe I should apply a mix of erosion and  dilation ( https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm ), but no code samples there!

Comment: erosion/dilation code samples (damn Python!) https://www.javatpoint.com/opencv-erosion-and-dilation

Comment: Found erase/dilate examplee in javascript, together with combination of them: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d76/tutorial_js_morphological_ops.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several experiments (based on [these examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d76/tutorial_js_morphological_ops.html)) and tests, I ended up with this code:

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let M = cv.Mat.ones(3, 3, cv.CV_8U);
let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);

cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete(); M.delete();
```

Probably it is possible to get even better results by concatenating multiple further filters, anyway already in this way I have acceptable results.

Full source image:
[image: Source]

Edited, but data untouched:

[image: annotated]

Processed by above code ("dilate"):

[image: processed]

Submitted to [webplotdigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) (look at settings on the right; yellow area is the only one processed by webplotdigitizer):

[image: submitted to webplotdigitizer]

Raw processing by webplotdigitizer ; some stray points appear, but they can be easily manually deleted:

[image: digitized]

Cleaned up:

[image: cleaned]

Re-plotted:

[image: replotted]

Note: in original image, horizontal and vertical scales are different: horizontal one is 4x w.r.t vertical one; resizing vertically 4x I get:

[image: resized]

Overlaying final image on source image, we can see it matches perfectly:

[image: overlay]

Of course it would be better to have digitization inside the same source code, but this is another story...